# How do I define the stereochemical configuration (R/S nomenclature) for this case?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I am aware of the R/S configuration of chiral centers in which the molecule is depicted in dash wedge form.

I wanted to know how the configuration would be mentioned if a chiral center is attached with:

> - two atoms/groups in wedge position
> - one atom at dash position, and
> - only one straight line bond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hmm, I'm not sure what do you exactly mean by the representation, but I'm guessing that it'd be something similar to the one I've drawn. Such a case is not possible because when we represent something by a wedge/dash configuration we plan to represent a $\text{3D}$ molecule in a $\text{2D}$ drawing sheet of paper.

In reality the chiral molecule with four different groups is $\pu{sp3}$ hybrid, which means that it exists as a tetrahedron.  The wedge actually mean that the group points towards you, and the dash means it is going away from you. And by *going towards* or *going away*, we mean along a line that's perpendicular to your drawing sheet.

Now that you can't have two groups approaching you perpendicular to the drawing sheet, talking about the configuration makes no sense here.

Comment: I agree with you . And what you've drawn is exactly what i was looking for..